# Problem in solving a question related to Sandwich theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**The question is** :

> Show that by Sandwich theorem the sequence  $\left\{\left(1 + \frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n} \right\}_n$ converges to $e$.

Now,what I have done is that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n} < \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}$.But I fail to construct another part of the inequality.So,Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is it?

Comment: Please, at least put brackets. As it is, it is difficult to know what it is. Thanks.

Comment: It converges to $e$, not $e^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left(1+\frac1{3n+2}\right)^{3n}\le \left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{3n}\le\left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}
$$ or $$
\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{3n+2}\right)^2}\left(1+\frac1{3n+2}\right)^{3n+2}\le \left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{3n}\le\left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}
$$ then conclude with the sandwich theorem, using $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{3n+2}\right)^2}=1$ and using
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{N}\right)^{N}=e^x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n-1} \le \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}
$$

such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1} = e,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n-1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1} \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{-3}=e\times 1 =e.
$$

Comment: Yeah I have understood.I am too silly and dull.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can write the term of interest as

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}\right)^{3n/(3n+1)}$$

Then noting that $1-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{3n}{3n+1}<1$, we can write

$$\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1} \tag 1$$

Inasmuch as the left-hand and right-hand sides of $(1)$ approach $e$ as $n\to \infty$, the squeeze theorem guarantees that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^{3n}=e}$$

as was to be shown!